# Cadence IC6.1.7 Installation

Tags: cadence

I want to install Cadence IC6.1.7 (Custom IC / Analog / RF Design) and Mentor Graphic Calibre tools on RHEL 8.2 server. I want to make the following things work after the installation:

1. Circuit Design: Virtuoso Schematic Editor
2. Circuit Simulation: ADE-L, ADEXL using Spectre simulator
3. Layout Design: Virtuoso Layout Suite L, XL, GXL
4. Layout Verification: Mentor Graphics Calibre: nmDRC, nmLVS, xRC

Where should I find documentation to fulfill the tasks?

Thanks!

Comment: I did this in the past but forgot. I think you start with InstallScape and install the packages you want. Did you do that already?

Comment: @divB yes, I have done the InstallScape portion already. But I am not sure about the rest of the steps.

Comment: Then these things are probably already installed. All packages have a documentation directory with PDF documentation. Have you looked at these already? Sorry I can't be more help because I don't have access to the installations any longer

Comment: @divB I think I need to adjust the path variables. I am using Linux system for the firsts time. Having a hard time understanding how to fix those. Yes, I looked into the documents. The problem is it says if I type cadencehelp in the command line it will pop up another window that contains the details but in my case, it returns no such command not found. Also, when I type virtuoso no window is coming and I can't access the help tab. That is why I am looking for a document that guides what paths needs to fix.

Comment: Normally you just have to start “virtuoso”. Try that. If it doesn’t work, use “find” to see where the executable isnwithin the installation) and add this to your path (export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/virtuoso if you’re using bash)